# Early bind microsoft activex data objects 6.1 library in SSIS VB script

Tags: vba, vb.net, ssis

I am trying to convert several of my ms access VBA scheduled tasks over to SSIS. 
In VBA I use the  `microsoft activex data objects 6.1` library. To my surprise,  much of my code compiled fine. When I try to execute the task however, I am presented with a non-sense runtime error. I was also getting warnings about late binding. My thought is that perhaps if I can remove the late binding and early bind, the error might go away

```
Public Sub open_ADOConn(Optional connection_String As String = postgresConnString)
    ADOConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'late binding
    ADOConn.ConnectionString = connection_String
    ADOConn.Open
End Sub

Public Sub Main()
    ' Add your code here
    Call open_ADOConn()    'call 
    Call MsgBox("hello")
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are converting a project why not convert to ADO.net?

Comment: I am confused. You say ms Access, then a postgresConnString and you want to use SSIS which I think is for  MS Sql Server.

Comment: I am looking to open a connection string to a server of my choice. SSIS can be used to do many things including connect to Postgres. I am just trying to get into Postgres.